# Smartsheet SDK is throwing an error caused job failure in databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, sdk, databricks

I have set up which pulls data from smartsheet thru SDK. It uses smartsheet-python-sdk module.
Suddenly I started receiving an error -type object Retry has no attribute 'Default_allowed_methods'

This error comes at below

Import smartsheet

Smart=smartsheet.Smartsheet(token) ---- at this point above error occurred

Please help...

I checked smartsheet token which is not expired. It is not communicating to smartsheet api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrade SDK to 3.0.0, it worked for me, and let them figure out the actual bug

Comment: Do you mean Smartsheet python SDK lib..i am just installing it without mentioning any verson name. Do I need to mention version name like pip install smartsheet python SDK 3.0.0.